# The network path was not found Error / MVC-Entity Framwork

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The network path was not found
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network
>   path was not found
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +6573870    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +717

---

Hello,

I have database connection error above as you can see. But my connectionstring is fine, because i used same connectionstring on different site published another port on IIS. Furthermore, i can read data from sql but can't insert anything. I searched lots of time on google but i didnt work. I think i am missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify: You can read, just not crate/update? Or you can not connect at all?

Comment: İ can read but i can't insert data. İts strange..

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue. Check my answer below, make sure your app has permissions to your db.

Comment: how should i set my connection string in this case? I created with sa login on my local.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the Application Pool Identity has  permissions to your database.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem. The problem is bin folder was not update. After build the project and deployed it againg, insert problem fixed.