# 'The network path was not found' every first attempt to Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, dns

I am developing a web application, using Visual Studio 2013 and a SQL SERVER database created on Azure.

Almost every time that I took more than 30 seconds to build and re-run the application (F5) I get this error below. The connection sql connection to SQL Timed-out and this is the error raised.

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]

I retry the connection and the problem goes away.
The point is that I am loosing so much time on this issue.

**INFO ADDED:**

- I have the SAME issue on SQL Management, first attempt network not found, second attempt it works.
- I have seen other computers, running other apps (.net based) on the company with the same behavior on a different SQL Azure server, so, in my mind is something related to azure dns.
- I have two SQL connections, to the same server, one for OWIN context, and another used by Entity Framework 6. Both MARS enable.
- I don't feel to having the same issue browsing any other website.
- My computer is part of an enterprise domain (that I had myself setup, and I am not an expert on Windows Server)
- I am using a Macbook with ThunderBolt dongle for ethernet.

**My connection strings**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Container" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MakeItMine.csdl|res://*/Models.**********.ssdl|res://*/Models.**********.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=**********.database.windows.net;initial catalog=db**********;persist security info=True;user id=**********;password=**********;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;Connection Timeout=3;ConnectRetryCount=3;ConnectRetryInterval=1&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="OWINConnection" connectionString="data source=**********.database.windows.net;initial catalog=db**********;persist security info=True;user id=**********;password=**********;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=MakeItMine;Connection Timeout=3;ConnectRetryCount=3;ConnectRetryInterval=1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**My IP settings**

[image: network details]

**What I tried**

- Disabled AVG Components
- Disabled Windows Firewall for Home/Enterprise
  networks
- Changed my dns to Google's dns (8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4), if I open
  nslookup and try to resolve my database path, it works every time.
- Changed my sql connection parameters: "Connection Timeout=3;ConnectRetryCount=3;ConnectRetryInterval=1", so it takes less time to raise the error, and I can retry faster and not loose so much time.

Azure doesn't permit me "pinging" the server, since never returns. So, I am really in trouble on how to troubleshoot/monitor this issue.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this are appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your connection string (less passwords/sensitive info)? And are you saying the web app itself is hosted in Azure? (as a VM or an app service web app?)

Comment: @RussellYoung added! No, the web app is running locally. The SQL Server is on Azure, even during development.

Comment: How are you managing the firewall rules on the sql db?  I don't see how that could be the cause since it wouldn't fix itself after 30 seconds - did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017281/the-network-path-was-not-found-error-mvc-entity-framwork/35017370 ?  Also can you connect ok with the SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: @RussellYoung, I don't have any specific rule on firewall, I ever use that feature "Add my ip to firewall rules", since my other azure services would connect without problem directly. I saw this thread, but I am always building/rebuilding the project. I think that's is not the problem at all. And YES, I have the same problem occurring on SQL Management. That's an important information that I will add on this question.

Comment: So probably firewall is the problem - SQL Azure exposes a public end point, and as such implements a firewall around it - your services within Azure can access it, but no one outside of Azure can - if you're trying to get to it over the internet, and your client IP hasn't been added to the firewall for exclusion, you wont get in.  There is a feature in the latest SSMS which attempts to add your ip to the exclusion for you - this takes time and needs your creds.  Could possibly be that.  Add your ip to the firewall then try again, see if you get in 1st go.

Comment: @RussellYoung I don't think that this should by the problem. First, because I already have my IP there and the problem persists. And I can connect the database on the second try. If that was the problem I would never connect there until add my IP there. I am using SSMS 2014, but I never seen it acting like that (automatically adding my ip to firewall rules).

Answer (score 1):

I did not found the exact problem neither the perfect solution yet, but I do know its a DNS related problem.
So, my fix by now is changing my windows HOSTS file and fixing my database dns to its ip. It's working for now and saving me a lot of debugging time.

[image]